# Change calculator using C#

Tags: c#, while-loop

I am trying to write a program that takes price and amount paid and outputs the change denominations. I am having issues with the following.

- I will also like only applicable change denominations to be printed (I.e, if change is 71, only show FithyBills =1, TwentyBills=1 and Bills =1 and ignore the rest). Currently, it shows all with other recorded as Ten Bills=0 and so on).

Here is the code

```
using System;

namespace ChangeCalulator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Item Price: ");
            int price = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Amount Paid: ");
            int paid = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            while (paid < pice)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have paid less than the price");
                Console.Write("Paid: ");
                paid = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            }
            decimal changeamount = paid - price;

            Change change = new Change(changeamount);
            //This displays the change based on each denominantion
            Console.WriteLine($"Hundred SEK Bills: {change.HundredBills}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Fifty SEK Bills: {change.FiveBills}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Twenty SEK Bills: {change.TwentyBills}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Ten SEK Bills: {change.TenBills}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Five SEK Bills: {change.FiveBills}");
            Console.WriteLine($"One SEK: {change.Bills}");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    //The Change class  will create a public integer variable for each denomination and store the values.
    public class Change
    {
        private int changeamount;

        public int HundredBills { get; }
        public int FiftyBills { get; }
        public int TwentyBills { get; }
        public int TenBills { get; }
        public int FiveBills { get; }
        public int Bills { get; }
        //This calculates the number of each denomination the amount equals
        public Change(decimal price)
        {
            HundredBills = (int)(changeamount / 100);
            price %= 100;

            FiftyBills = (int)(changeamount / 50);
            price %= 50;

            TwentyBills = (int)(changeamount / 20);
            price %= 20;

            TenBills = (int)(changeamount / 10);
            price %= 10;

            FiveBills = (int)(changeamount / 5);
            price %= 5;

            Bills = (int)(changeamount / 1);
            price %= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what are the issues exactly? Don't make us guess or spend ages trying to figure it out. Explain exactly where you are stuck, please. Make it easier for people to help you!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on your 2nd point. Its not clear.  Suppose the bill is 71 then what do you want to print?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine($"Fifty SEK Bills: {change.FiveBills}");` Should that be `change.FiftyBills`?

Comment: I have made change and clarified the questions. Thanks you.

Comment: Looks like you need to recalculate `changeamount` after setting each `*Bills` amount. And check each `*Bills` property for 0 before calling `Console.WriteLine`. My previous comment remains...

Comment: `while (price < paid) { Console.WriteLine("You have paid less than the price");` makes no sense. The loop says "while the price is less than the amount paid", but the output says the opposite. What did you intend? I'd guess the loop should be `while (paid < price)` to ensure that the user adds sufficient funds.

Comment: @ADyson. You are right. That was a mistake when I was typing the code out. But even with the correction. The changeamont is still based on the initial amount entered.

Comment: " when I was typing the code out"...well that's a good argument for using copy & paste, I'd say :-)

Comment: P.S. adding a simple test e.g. `if (change.HundredBills > 0)` before each of your writeline commands for the change will ensure it only prints a change item if it actually needs to be given.

Comment: And other argument for copy & paste is that your edited version also has a typo in it - `pice`!

Comment: Thank @HereticMonkey. That has fixed the second issue

Comment: Also for the first issue. It was because I did not call price after the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor `public Change(decimal price)`, you need to use `price`:

```
public Change(decimal price)
{
    HundredBills = (int)(price / 100);
    price %= 100;

    FiftyBills = (int)(price / 50);
    price %= 50;

    TwentyBills = (int)(price / 20);
    price %= 20;

    TenBills = (int)(price / 10);
    price %= 10;

    FiveBills = (int)(price / 5);
    price %= 5;

    Bills = (int)(price / 1);
    price %= 1;
}
```

You can then remove the unneeded `changeamount` field.

*Working demo:* https://dotnetfiddle.net/NbyZPc

As for not printing the 0 amounts, a simple `if (theValue > 0)` check around each WriteLine should accomplish that.

Comment: Thanks. That has fixed the second issue